# Controls on WinForm not modifiable in Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, infragistics

I've inherited a project that has been modified in a way that is beyond me to undo. Every single control on the form is not modifiable in the designer except through the Properties window and each control has an icon in the area below (see image) in the section usually reserved for non-visible items (e.g. DataSource). How do I undo this and return the designer to a usable version without wiping it all out and starting over?

[image: Control Icons]

Comment: Are these derived classes?

Comment: If the class has been heavily edited manually, it's possible you will have to start over if you want to use the designer to maintain the form. Been there...

Comment: Some are Controls that I had created. Others are Infragistic controls. One or two are build in MS controls.

Comment: The form these controls are places on is just a Windows.UserControl

Comment: What happens when you attempt a build?

Comment: When I run into this sort of thing, blowing away the code, repulling the repo, build and then bring up the designer will usually fix the problem. Just a baseline thing to try.

Comment: Builds just fine. No errors, no warnings. Runs fine. Just can't make changes to anything without using the properties window. I did try the rebuild but this is actually a problem with every UserControl and form in this solution.

Comment: @notJoeKing Have you verified that you have the correct version of NetAdvantage installed and that the designers for the controls are loaded properly?  Do you have the same issue if you drag a NetAdvantage control from your toolbox onto a form in a new project?

Answer (score 0):

Could the controls be locked? I have run into legacy code in which the programmers have locked every single control, meaning you cannot move or resize them in the designer. If so, select them all and change the `Locked` property to false (you should also see a padlock in the designer when you select them, if they are locked.

If not, well maybe you can create a new dialog/form and copy the controls unto it and see if that clears things up. Another trick could be to add a second instance of the user control(s) to see if the newly added control works as expected. If so, go through the code and point all events/logic to the new control (tedious yes, but may work).

Also, you can never edit individual sub-controls of a user control in the designer for the form/control where you instantiated the user control. You must go to the designer of the user control to edit individual (sub)controls of a user control.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The form is not locked. Clicking on any control on the UserControl just places focus on the entire UserControl and brings up it's properties in the Properties window. I'll try creating a new UC

Comment: Hm, so you cannot edit individual controls? Are you sure you edit the correct user control? You can never edit individual sub-controls of a user control that is placed on another control/form. You need to open up the original user controls designer to edit any sub-control.

Comment: Hmmm... your comment seems to indicate that you do see the user controls. In which case there's nothing odd about you not being able to modify different parts of any single user control via the designer. If you open the user control itself (rather than the form or even containing user control that **uses** it), does it become editable in the designer?

Comment: Tried creating a new UserControl. The very first Infragistic control I put on there created that section and placed the control in it but regular win controls act as expected.

Comment: @notJoeKing is that in the same project or a new project?  If in the same project, what is the behavior in a new project?  If it is reproduced in a new project, does running the Toolbox utility that Infragistics provides correct the behavior in a new project?

Answer (score 0):

If the Infragistics controls are shown in the Component Tray, than there might be version differences. What you could try is to open the licenses.licx file and remove the content from there. Do you have an Infragistics controls installed on your machine? Are there any difference after setting the "Specific Version" property of the Infragistics assemblies to "false"?

Is this happening only in your existing project or the same behavior is reproducible in a new project as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the dll that contains the controls you can't modify in the designer.

the steps are:

- right click in the ToolBox in visual studio designer (on General for example).
- select Choose Items...
- after a while vs load items press browse and select the dll
  interested than the componet should appear in the grid.  Do this for
  all the dll that contains the controls you are interested.

  -Make sure you have checked the component (use filter text box if you
  have a lot of component loaded).
- press ok.

  Now you should be able to move controls in designer.

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen behavior this when a user control or form is incorrectly flagged as a 'Component'.

Some manual hacking of the .csproj file may be the answer then. Open the project file in a text editor, and find the references to your control. If you find a subtype defined as:

```
<Compile Include="MyControl.cs">
  <SubType>Component</SubType>
</Compile>
```

The forms designer will interpret it as such. You can change the 'SubType' to 'UserControl' to fix it.