# Winforms control (ObjectListview) shows up as componenten in form tray instead of visual control on canvas

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, objectlistview

I have made several controls over the past time through Folder > Add > User Control, then dragging an ObjectListview onto the designer and setting anchor/ dock etc then implementing the code.

Since this morning when drag an Objectlistview onto a control, it shows up as a component in the bottom tray instead of on the control's design canvas.

I can't remember installing any updates on either visual studio or the ObjectListview NuGet package, it's still 2.9.5 from 2017. The behaviour is the same in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 preview.. 
I did install .Net Core SDK 2.2.402 ealier this week but this project references Framework 4.6.1..

When I add a standard TreeView or ListView etc onto the form they get added normally.

I'm comparing the code with other controls I created this way, both derive from UserControl. The control that works as normal has the line near the end of `InitializeComponent()`

```
   this.Controls.Add(this.objectListView1);
```

For some reason for new controls I create that line isn't generated by the designer for ObjectListview.

If I manually add that line to InitializeComponent() the control does show up on the design canvas but I can't select it or do anything with it.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this changed behaviour and how to fix this? I'm working sundays b/c I'm very busy this is really messing me up.

Comment: Having controls turn into components shown at the bottom of the designer is an obscure failure mode in the Winforms designer.  A probably better example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342720/controls-on-winform-not-modifiable-in-designer).  Problem is that nobody can show a good repro and nobody tells us how they worked around the problem.  In general this kind of misery is caused by an exception at design-time.  Ought to show a message box with a cryptic description, programmers tend to dismiss it and putter on for a while trying to figure out what happened.

Comment: Restore from source control to fix the damage.  Diagnose hard cases by running VS again, attach to the 1st instance and force the debugger to stop on all CLR exceptions.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks you for your (as always valuable) input. I was just able to fix it by uninstalling en reinstalling the NuGet package. No idea what happened here but I'm on my way again!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix by uninstalling and reinstalling the nuget package.